# Actors common to both Pleasantville and Buffy the Vampire Slayer

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer, pleasantville

Who are the actors common to both [Pleasantville](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleasantville_%28film%29) and [Buffy the Vampire Slayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer)?

As part of my grieving process over the death of [Paul Walker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Walker) who was in the [Fast & the Furious
franchise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fast_and_the_Furious), I was researching his life.  It surprised me that he was also in Pleasantville since it is one 
of my favorite movies and I had not connected the actor to both films (and would *never* have recognized 
him in a million years).

This got me to thinking about the actors I **had** noticed as common between **BtVS** (another of my 
favorite shows) and Pleasantville, since I had already spotted 3 of them.

- [Danny Strong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Strong), plays 'Jukebox Boy' in Pleasantville and [Jonathan Levinson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Levinson) in BtVS.
- [Marc Blucas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Blucas), plays an unnamed youth in the Pleasantville High School basketball team and [Riley Finn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riley_Finn) in BtVS.
- [Nancy Lenehan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Lenehan), plays the mother of a girl who's tongue turns an 'odd color' in Pleasantville as well as Pat in [Dead Man's Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Man%27s_Party_%28Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer%29).

Are there any I missed?

Comment: Huh..  Do any of the lurking down-voters care to explain their reasoning?

Comment: There are currently 8 actors in Pleasantville. Look at this link for the others you missed. http://angel.fcpages.com/pv.html

Comment: This edit is in contention on meta: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2243/ and I have flagged this to be locked pending moderator review of the meta issue. Please keep the meta issues on the meta topic instead of the comments here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are 17 people (at least) who [worked on both projects](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0120789,tt0118276). About half are crew and one is stuntwork (which is kind of both).

**ACTORS**

- Mark Blucas
- Danny Strong (actor on Buffy, cameo & crew on Pleasantville)
- Jason Behr
- Nancy Lenehan
- Denise Dowse
- Andrea Baker
- Paul Morgan Stetler
- J. Patrick Lawlor
- Joseph Benjamin Stewart

**CREW**

- Jacob Chambers (stunts)
- Randy Eriksen
- Tim Speed
- Kenneth Hunter
- Jeff Orsa
- Elizabeth Rabe
- Chadwick Cohn
- Kenneth Estes

Comment: That was a better answer than I was expecting!  Thank you so much..  Now I'm compelled to go through the list and identify where each actor fits in the relevant show.

Comment: This answer would be even better with a summary of the link content, e.g. a short list of the people and what their job was.

Comment: You've missed Barbara Harris :-) http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0120789,tt0103893