# Was this character from 'Better Call Saul' also in 'Breaking bad'?

Tags: character, breaking-bad, better-call-saul

In the latest episode of 'Better Call Saul', we saw Saul aka Jimmy saving that guy (obviously staged) hanging from that billboard. Among the crowd, I noticed this lady and I thought I had seen her in **Breaking Bad** too.
Maybe, the skank, or the neighbor of Walter white himself.

Here's [The link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMZ1t.jpg) to that photo of that lady I took as snapshot.

[image]

Comment: It looks nothing like the skank from BB.  She ([Dale Dickey](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0225460/?ref_=tt_cl_t12)) was also in Iron Man 3 as the mother of one of the injured troops on Extremis and she has much more 'exaggerated' features than the woman seen here.

Comment: I thought, maybe, i have seen her somewhere in BrBa. At first, this woman reminded me of 'Wendy' then i tried to compare and i was wrong again.

Comment: In fact, that looks more like [Nancy Lenehan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Lenehan) who was in both [Pleasantville and Buffy the Vampire Slayer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/15855/566) though I don't recall her being in Breaking Bad..

Comment: I am afraid i haven't watched 'Buffy the vampire slayer' yet. I guess, i will watch it tonight.

Comment: Oh, she's only in one episode of BtVS.  ..[Dead Man's Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Man%27s_Party_%28Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer%29).  It is ***way*** funny though, in that she has a 'significant role'.

Comment: Is 'The Skank' an actual character title in BB?

Comment: @DA. As much as I understood the question, it's not only about the actress but also about the character, therefore *"lady"* might not be that inaccurate a term at all.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson yes, I think 'character' is a better word. Updated.

Comment: Thought of Nancy Lenehan too, but this woman looks a bit younger than her (Lenehan is 61).

Comment: She actually looks a little bit like Jesse's mom.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The character is played by [Staci Robbins](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1754312/). She has been credited simply as a Lady Onlooker.

Also as mentioned in the comments, it is not [Dale Dickey](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0225460), she plays Spooge's wife. Wendy (the crack whore) is played by [Julia Minesci](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2928008/) and Carol (Walt's neighbor) is played by [Cheryl Ford Mente](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm5826452/).

She is a spectator appearing to hold no real significance in the Breaking Bad universe.

Comment: Congratulations, this answer is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).